# Set uibarbuttonitem from child view

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uibarbuttonitem, childviews

I have a parent view controller and a child table view controller each embedded in a navigation view controller. It looks like so:

[image]

I want to make it so when I click the button Done, the Next button is enabled. I have tried to use `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` but no luck, tried other things such as setting `vc.nextButton.isEnable = True` but nope. I've been working on this for a few hours with no avail. Please explain your solution as well.

Here is the whole thing

[image]

Comment: How are you defining vc?

Comment: `ExampleViewController *vc = [[ExampleViewController alloc] init]` @rdelmar

Comment: That's just creating a new instance, it's not the one you have on screen. If this code is in the child view controller, you can access the parent with self.parentViewController. You might need to use self.navigationController.parentViewController if the controller is embedded in a navigation controller. You should check the class of self.parentViewController to see what it is.

Comment: uploaded another image to show you what I have set up @rdelmar

Comment: It's your app, so you need to figure out the relationships between your controllers, I'm not going to do it for you. Try throwing some logs in there, and see what they give you.